# conditional format based on text in cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet which has 2 sheets, 1 sheet called 'Search' and one called 'raw_data'.

The 'raw_data' sheet will have 3 columns A,B and C which holds the postcode data the administrator will enter in.

When a user enters in a postcode within cell A1 on the 'Search' sheet, this cell will then conditional format based on whether this postcode is found in column A,B or C in the 'raw_data' sheet.

If found in column A it will highlight Red, Column B Amber and Column C Green

I know this must be possible but have my weekend head on and not getting anywhere. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Search` sheet, cell `A1`, add the following three "Conditional format rules", under "Format cells if...", select "Custom formula is" and enter the following formula:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("raw_data!A:A"),A$1)>=1`

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("raw_data!B:B"),A$1)>=1`

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("raw_data!C:C"),A$1)>=1`

Select the color you want to apply to each rule. This is a sample of how each rule should look:

[image]