# Extract values of conditional formating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that has literally hundreds of conditional formatting rules within it. All the rules are 'text is exactly' rules and includes postcodes such as BH17, CA24 etc.

I have recently amended the spreadsheet as per the following as the sheet was becoming slow due to the volume of rules: [conditional format based on text in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75952533/conditional-format-based-on-text-in-cells)

Is there any way to extract the text from the rules based on the color of conditional formatting i.e pull all green rules and place the postcodes extracted into a column so that I can enter them into the correct columns or am I looking at the tedious task of starting from scratch as I am highly expecting?

**Edit**
To confirm, I am looking to see if I could extract the text from conditional rules so an example using the image below would be: if I wanted to extract the postcodes for all rules that have an orange color attached it would put these values into a column somewhere, AB10,AB11,AB12,AB13 etc

[image: conditional_rules]

Hope that makes sense but if not feel free to ask.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Is there any way to extract the text from the rules based on the color of conditional formatting i.e pull all green rules and place the postcodes extracted into a column so that I can enter them into the correct columns or am I looking at the tedious task of starting from scratch as I am highly expecting?`, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I've edited the question to try and explain better, I don't think it's possible personally but thought would be worth an ask.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your added image is your sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, where can I see your expected result using your sample input situation? For example, you want to retrieve the values of "AB10", "AB11",,, and put the values to a column? And, in your situation, which do you want to retrieve the values from one sheet or all sheets?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer including 2 patterns. Please confirm them. If those are not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to extract the values and colors from all conditional formatting rules applied to a given `Sheet1` sheet and paste it to a sheet named `Result`:

### The code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const resultSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Result");

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Solution')
    .addItem('ExtractValues', 'extractValues')
    .addToUi();
}

function extractValues() {
  const conditionalFormatRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  if (conditionalFormatRules.length > 0) {
    const colors = {};
    conditionalFormatRules.forEach(rule => {
      var color = rule.getBooleanCondition().getBackground();
      if (!(color in colors)) {
        colors[color] = [];
      }
      colors[color].push(rule.getBooleanCondition().getCriteriaValues());
    })
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(colors).length; i++) {
      color = Object.keys(colors)[i];
      resultSheet.getRange(1, i + 1).setValue(color).setBackground(color);
      resultSheet.getRange(2, i + 1, colors[color].length).setValues(colors[color]).setBackground(color);
    }
  }
}
```

### Working example:

- It will group the results under its respective colors.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the conditional formatting rules and want to put the values in a column of the Spreadsheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are retrieved from all sheets in the active Spreadsheet.

```js
function sample1() {
  const color = "#FF9900"; // Please set the background color you set. This sample is Orange in color.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const values = sheets.reduce((ar, s) => {
    s.getConditionalFormatRules().forEach(c => {
      const t = c.getBooleanCondition();
      if (t.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.BooleanCriteria.TEXT_EQUAL_TO && t.getBackground().toUpperCase() == color) {
        ar.push(c.getBooleanCondition().getCriteriaValues()); // or ar.push([c.getBooleanCondition().getCriteriaValues().join(",")]);
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the conditional formatting rules of all sheets. And, put the values in column "A" of the destination sheet.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values are retrieved from a single sheet in the active Spreadsheet.

```js
function sample2() {
  const color = "#FF9900"; // Please set the background color you set. This sample is Orange in color.
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const values = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules().reduce((ar, c) => {
    const t = c.getBooleanCondition();
    if (t.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.BooleanCriteria.TEXT_EQUAL_TO && t.getBackground().toUpperCase() == color) {
      ar.push(c.getBooleanCondition().getCriteriaValues()); // or ar.push([c.getBooleanCondition().getCriteriaValues().join(",")]);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the conditional formatting rules of "Sheet1" sheet. And, put the values in column "A" of the destination sheet.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the hex color of `#FF9900` is used from `all rules that have an orange color` of your question. If this color code was different from your actual situation, please modify it.

#### References:

- [getConditionalFormatRules()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getconditionalformatrules)
- [Class ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)